# Java NullPointerException when there are no variables not initialiased

Tags: java, compiler-errors, nullpointerexception, initialization

I am creating this login form using java swing and what I basically do is I get the values from the relevant JtextFields and send them onto another class. Thereafter I check it with the database records. However the program is always displaying a NullPointerException everytime I run it. I tested every variable and saw that none of them contain any Null Values at all.

This is the first method (in the LoginPage class) that gets the values from the JTextField

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
String user=textField.getText();
String pass=String.valueOf(passwordField.getPassword());

//try{
//if((user!=null)&&(pass!=null)){
//  System.out.println("user is not null");

ui.sendLogin(user,pass);

//}else{}
//}catch(NullPointerException ex){
    //System.out.println("Entered catch block og view"+ex.getMessage());
//}
```

}

Thereafter it calls this method (in class LoginController)

```
public void sendLogin(String user, String pass) {
try{
    System.out.println("values from sendLogin"+user+"pass"+pass);
    model.verifyUser(user,pass);
}catch(NullPointerException ex){
    System.out.println("Entered catch block os sendLogin"+ex);
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Finally the verifyUser method (in class LoginModel) checks it with the database

```
 public void verifyUser(String user,String pass){           
        String username="";
        String password="";
        String acc="";
         try{
             String sql="SELECT * FROM users";
             con1.getInstance();
             Statement st = con1.getConn().createStatement();
             ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
             rs.next();     
             username=rs.getString("username");
             password=rs.getString("password");
             acc=rs.getString("accountType");
             if(username.equals(user)&&password.equals(pass)){
                 System.out.println("Logged into the system");
                 global_username=username;
                 accountType=acc;
             }else{
                 System.out.println("Unsuccessful login"+username+user+password+pass);
             }
            st.execute(sql);  
        } catch (SQLException s){
            System.out.println("SQL statement is not executed!"+s);
        }

}
```

This is the Stack Trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.application.view.LoginController.sendLogin(LoginController.java:64)
    at org.application.view.LoginPage$2.actionPerformed(LoginPage.java:94)
user is not null
values from sendLoginapassabc
Entered catch block os sendLoginjava.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Have you checked that `model != null`?

Comment: Although I agree with people suggesting that `model` is `null`, you posted contents of `sendLogin` method twice, while one of them is supposed to be `verifyUser`

Comment: Which is LoginController.java line 64? The stack trace indicates that in this line is the error... It could be `model` object or the `verifyUser`function

Comment: @mustafabattal yes I have mistakenly posted the same method twice. Sorry about it I corrected it now. TheCharliemopsthe LoginController line 64 is model.verifyUser(user,pass)

Answer (score 5):

Measure, don't guess.

Why guess which variable is null? The stack trace gives you the line number where the exception happens. Fire up the debugger and set a breakpoint on line 64 of the `LoginController` class.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the `model` variable is null and causing the `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your `model` variable is null.
That is what is causing your `NullPointerException`.

Is this line 64 `model.verifyUser(user,pass);`

Comment: Well then that is the error. You need to check why model is null and fix it

Answer (score 1):

I bet the `model` variable is `null`.